# How to round off to 3 decimal places in psql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, floating-point, rounding, psql

```
select trim(TO_CHAR((15000.991234)::float, '999G999G99G999G99G99G990D99'))  as qty

Expected Output:
15,000.991
```

I want 3 decimal precison (3 numbers after point (dot)) and at the same time i want comma separation too and want result in char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra `9` to your string:

```
SELECT trim(to_char((15000.991234)::float, '999G999G99G999G99G99G990D999'))  as qty 

    qty     
------------
 15.000,991
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f9c8c3777c986f733963f79317caa73f)

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
select trim(TO_CHAR((round(15000.991234, 3))::float, '999G999G99G999G99G99G990D999'))  as qty
```

Just use the `round` function before converting it to char.

Edit:
Forgot to mention you were missing a '9' and the end of the format-string.